# switch sprite image continuously(not to show animation)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Using below code, i can able to change color of my CCSprite continuously,BUT i need to change my CCSprite image with this code. How can i do that?

NOTE: Don't want to show just animation where frame changes, i need to select one of the sprite that changes continuously later in my code.

```
 id delayTime1 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.05f];
    id calFun1   = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        //HERE SET BLUE TEXTURE..
       // m_spriteBubbleWeapon= [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstimage.png"]];// //kill when i uncomment it 

        m_spriteBubbleWeapon.color = ccc3(255,0,255); // works current

    }];
    id delayTime2 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.05f];
    id calFun2   = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        //HERE SET RED TEXTURE..
        //m_spriteBubbleWeapon= [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"second image.png"]];//kill when i uncomment it

        m_spriteBubbleWeapon.color = ccc3(255,0,0);//work correct

    }];

    id sequece = [CCSequence actions:delayTime1, calFun1, delayTime2, calFun2, nil];
    id repeate = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequece];

    [sprite runAction:repeate];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a property tex1 and tex2 earlier in the class (e.g. in init):

```
CCTexture2D* tex1 = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"firstimage.png"];
CCTexture2D* tex2 = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"secondimage.png"];
```

Then swap the texture for the existing sprite in your code:

```
id delayTime1 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.05f];
id calFun1   = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    //HERE SET BLUE TEXTURE..
    [m_spriteBubbleWeapon setTexture:tex1];
    m_spriteBubbleWeapon.color = ccc3(255,0,255); // works current
}];
```

...

```
    //HERE SET RED TEXTURE..
    [m_spriteBubblWeapon setTexture:tex2];
```